# I need help creating a script to pull the current dates for the week

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm not very familiar with JavaScript but I want to create a script that will pull the every single day of the week for me. Here is what I am working with right now. 
[image]

I added the picture "Get date" and I would like to make it so that when I hit the "get date" button, it will go through the script and assign dates to the cells above Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc. as 8/8, 8/9, 8/10.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to do it in two steps:

1. Find the last Monday (which is up to 6 days in the past)
2. Starting from there, build a list of 7 days

```js
var date = new Date(),
    daysOfWeek = [];

// find last Monday
while(date.getDay() != 1) {
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
}

// build array of dates
for(var n = 0; n < 7; n++) {
  daysOfWeek.push((date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
}

console.log(daysOfWeek);
```